# while(cin) как выйти из данного цикла

Tags: c++

Разбираю калькулятор из книги Страуструпа, лексемы вроде как считывает правильно, но не могу понять как выйти из цикла. Если ввожу ctrl + z выдаёт ошибку.

```
    using namespace std;

class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value 
    Token(char ch)    // make a Token from a char
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token get_token()    // read a token from cin
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
        //not yet   case ';':    // for "print"
        //not yet   case 'q':    // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8', val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
    }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}

vector<Token> tok; 

int main()
{

    while (cin) {
        Token t = get_token();
        tok.push_back(t);

        //cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<tok.size(); ++i) {
        if (tok[i].kind == '*') {    // we found a multiply!
            double d = tok[i - 1].value*tok[i + 1].value;

            // now what?
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: где  тут цикл?..

Comment: @ARHovsepyan while (cin) {
        Token t = get_token();
        tok.push_back(t);

        //cout << 1 << endl;
    }

Comment: да, почему то я сначала не увидел  main()

Comment: ну там наверное по символу 'q' нужно сделать cin не валидным

Comment: типа std::basic_ios::setstate
`cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit)`
и while(cin) дальше не пойдёт

Comment: @Андрей Маврин,  когда устанавливается флаг  failbit, то просто после этого  поток не считывает следующий символ, и цикл прекратится

Answer (score 3):

Неохота расписать ошибки, просто смотрите внимательно и сравните

```
using namespace std;
//тут лучше определить конструктор по умолчанию тоже
class Token {
public:
    char kind;        // what kind of token
    double value;     // for numbers: a value
    Token(char ch = ' ')  // здесь!!!  // make a Token from a char
        :kind(ch), value(0) { }
    Token(char ch, double val)     // make a Token from a char and a double
        :kind(ch), value(val) { }
};

//------------------------------------------------------------------------------

Token get_token()    // read a token from cin
{
    Token t;
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
    //not yet   case ';':    // for "print"
    //not yet   case 'q':    // for "quit"
    case '=':
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself

    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8', val);   // let '8' represent "a number"

    }
    default:
        cerr << "Bad token";
    }
    return Token(ch);
}
int main()
{        
    vector<Token> tok;        
    while (cin ) {
        Token t = get_token();
        tok.push_back(t);                        
        //из цикла выходить нужно  вводя EOF (у меня это  ctrl + z )
       //  if (t.kind == '=') break;
       }
    for (size_t i = 0; i<tok.size(); ++i) {
        if (tok[i].kind == '*') {    // we found a multiply!
            double d = tok[i - 1].value*tok[i + 1].value;
            // now what? 
            cout << d;  
            break;      
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

- из цикла нужно выходить вводя символ EOF(конец ввода): в моей системе
  это ctrl+z.     Из цикла можно выходить также определив удобный для
  себя символ - например символ '=' что я и написал в цикле как комментарий

Comment: Кстати да, можно было вообще просто по определённому kind break делать, чё-то меня опять не в ту степь понесло =)

Comment: а ошибку у него выдавало потому что там в switch по дефолту вызывается error("Bad token"). Или нет ?

Comment: @vegorov,  да нужно там добавить символ конца ввода конечно, но можно просто ничего не добавлять, EOF  закроет цикл

Comment: ну мне кстати кажется что EOF это только один из вариантов. А если нужно будет несколько выражений подряд вычислять? Тут наверное правильнее добавлять обработку некоторых символов как управляющую инструкцию (попытаться вычислить последнее введёное выражение и начать ввод нового выражения/закончить ввод выражений)

Comment: @ vegorov , да, для этого существует  например символ ';'  в наших кодах

Comment: @ARHovsepyan  Да, я после публикации заметил, что по дефолту там стоит error, а первый конструктор зачем там определять? Просто правило хорошего тона? Спасибо большое за поправки!

Answer (score 1):

```
Token get_token()    // read a token from cin
{
    char ch;
    cin >> ch;    // note that >> skips whitespace (space, newline, tab, etc.)

    switch (ch) {
        //not yet   case ';':    // for "print"
    case 'q': 
         cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit);
         return Token(ch);   // for "quit"
    case '(': case ')': case '+': case '-': case '*': case '/':
        return Token(ch);        // let each character represent itself
    case '.':
    case '0': case '1': case '2': case '3': case '4':
    case '5': case '6': case '7': case '8': case '9':
    {
        cin.putback(ch);         // put digit back into the input stream
        double val;
        cin >> val;              // read a floating-point number
        return Token('8', val);   // let '8' represent "a number"
    }
    default:
        error("Bad token");
    }
}

vector<Token> tok; 

int main()
{

    while (cin) {
        Token t = get_token();
        if (!cin)
            break;
        tok.push_back(t);

        //cout << 1 << endl;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i<tok.size(); ++i) {
        if (tok[i].kind == '*') {    // we found a multiply!
            double d = tok[i - 1].value*tok[i + 1].value;

            // now what?
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Я не компилировал не проверял, может опечатался где или точку с запятой забыл.

Comment: Работает, можно пожалуйста объяснить, что cin.setstate(std::ios_base::failbit); конкретно делает?

Comment: а я толком и не знаю, я открыл документацию на std::cin, нашёл там метод setstate, там пишут что он выставляет флаги состояния. operator bool(), которым вы пользуетесь в цикле while(cin), является аналогом !cin.fail(), а функция fail() в свою очередь при выставленном std::ios_base::failbit вернёт true, тогда operator bool() вернёт false, и вы выйдете из цикла. Почитайте документацию на std::basic_ios::setstate, так понятнее наверное будет.